# Issue Connecting Eclipse Maven Web Project To MYSQL -- only a type can be imported

Tags: java, mysql, maven

I unfortunately deleted my class project accidentally and am working on restoring it (have some files saved, created a new project on Eclipse to get everything going again and restructured). I am currently stuck on connecting my MySQL database to my application. This is my code:

index.jsp

```
<%@page import="com.DB.DBConnect" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AppUp - CUS 1156</title>
<%@include file="all_component/all_css.jsp"%>

<style type="text/css">
.back-img {
    background: url("img/header-image.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <%@include file="all_component/navbar.jsp"%>
    
<% Connection conn=DBConnect.getConn(); 
out.println(conn);
%>

    <div class="container-fluid back-img">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1 class="text-white p-4">
                <i class="fa fa-book mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>AppUp
            </h1>
<!--            <p class="text-white p-4">Apply For Entry Level Positions Seamlessly</p> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my DBConnect.java

```
package com.DB;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DBConnect {
    private static Connection conn;
    
    public static Connection getConn() {
        
        try {
            
            if(conn==null) {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/***schema name***","root","*********password*****");
                        
            }
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        
        return conn;
    }

}
```

and this is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.prog</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjectCUS1156</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ProjectCUS1156 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
  
  <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.13</version>
</dependency>


  
  
  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    
    

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>ProjectCUS1156</finalName>
  
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
Exception Report

Message Unable to compile class for JSP:

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [/Users/teutaelazaj/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/work/Catalina/localhost/ProjectCUS1156/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.DB.DBConnect resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [26] in the jsp file: [/index.jsp]
DBConnect cannot be resolved
23: <body>
24:     <%@include file="all_component/navbar.jsp"%>
25:     
26: <% Connection conn=DBConnect.getConn(); 
27: out.println(conn);
28: %>
29: 


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:487)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:397)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:367)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

I am very confused by this because last time it worked perfectly. Any help at all would be extremely appreciated. Thank you so much

Comment: As a general comment, it's usually discouraged to execute data access from your view layer as this mixes different concerns, view layer and data layer. It's generally accepted that view logic and data access logic should be kept separate.

Comment: `dejavu` your problem in pom.xml replace it like in preveus my answer on issue

Comment: @стасевич thank you for your reply, unfortunately I did try it and it did not work

Comment: @imherebcsomethingisntworking replace pom. and if an error show it

Comment: @стасевич I still get the same error when I run on server -- org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.DB.DBConnect resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [29] in the jsp file: [/index.jsp]
DBConnect cannot be resolved

Comment: Pls someone help, I have no idea what to do :(